# execute a C# method asynchronously using Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method in a class that I need to execute twice asynchronously.
The class has a constructor which accepts URL as a parameter :

```
ABC abc= new ABC(Url);

// Create the thread object, passing in the abc.Read() method
// via a ThreadStart delegate. This does not start the thread.
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(abc.Read());


ABC abc1= new ABC(Url2)

// Create the thread object, passing in the abc.Read() method
// via a ThreadStart delegate. This does not start the thread.
Thread oThread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(abc1.Read());

// Start the thread
oThread.Start();
// Start the thread
oThread1.Start();
```

Is this the way it works? Can anyone help?

Comment: you can also try BackgroundWorker if it suits you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the parentheses to create a delegate:

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(abc.Read));
```

And do the same for `oThread1`. Here's [MSDN's Delegates Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks minitech.. how do you pass the parameter URL to the constructor?

Comment: @srikanth: It looks like you're already doing that... `abc.Read` can still refer to `this` properly.

Comment: i need to send two differenc URL for each instance of ABC class.

Comment: @srikanth: Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/OVMpA Are you storing the URL you pass to the constructor? Just access it with `this` as usual...

Comment: got it thank you very much. i can execute the Read method simultaneously with different url's. it's working fine. will it create any issues in prod?

Comment: i execute the above code in the windows service. the service runs every 10 secs. will it create deadlock while starting threads every 10 secs? will the thread.join stop the thread?

Comment: @srikanth: No, no deadlock unless you're accessing shared resources. `Thread.Join` in the right place will wait for the thread, and it'll cause a deadlock in the wrong place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7037/discussion-between-srikanth-and-minitech)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your `ThreadStart` creation to use the method as a target instead of invoking the method

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(abc.Read);
```

Notice how I used `abc.Read` instead of `abc.Read()`.  This version causes the `ThreadStart` delegate to point to the method `abc.Read`.  The original version `abc.Read()` was invoking the `Read` method immediately and trying to convert the result to a `ThreadStart` delegate.  This is likely not what you intended

Comment: @JaredPar.. how do you pass the parameter URL to the constructor of ABC class? i need to send two differenc URL for each instance of ABC class.

Comment: @srikanth are you trying to create the instances on the background thread?

Comment: r... i figured it out. Otherwise, the code that i have is working fine.. asynchronously executing the Read() method with different url's. Is that thread safe and will it create any issues once we move to Prod?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
Thread oThread1 = new Thread(() => abc1.Read());
```

You can pass a lambda in to the `Thread` constructor instead of newing up a new `ThreadStart` object.

Joseph Albahari has a great [online resource](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Passing_Data_to_a_Thread) about threading.  Very easy to read and lots of examples.